# Retrieve loss for each epoch in Python H2O

Tags: python, h2o, h2o.ai

I would like to plot a loss vs epoch graph from a deep quantile regression model in H2O. I'm using the H2ODeepLearningEstimator but can't seem to find a way to retrieve the loss like in Keras.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/display-deep-learning-model-training-history-in-keras/

Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you show your code?, have you look the H2O docs? https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/modeling.html?highlight=loss#h2o.estimators.deeplearning.H2ODeepLearningEstimator.loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [learning curve plot](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/explain.html#learning-curve-plot). In h2o you can retrieve the "scoring history" data using `model.scoring_history()`.

You can influence the frequency of scoring as well as amount of data used for the loss estimate using parameters prefixed with `score_`, e.g., `score_interval`, `score_validation_samples` etc.